# Qt/QML: Delay window rendering until data is available

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am building an application using Qt/QML. The QML of my main window is very complex and depends on lots of data which must be loaded via HTTP and then be processed by a C++ backend before it is ready to be displayed.

The C++ backend provides a signal which is fired when the data is ready. Until then, I want the window to be empty except for a simple loading indicator being displayed. Of course, I could use a simple overlay which hides my actual interface until the data is available, but this would mean that the QML code of my actual user interface is already loaded and tries to access the not-yet-available data, which is causing a lot of errors, so I would need to add dozens of dummy values and NOTIFY signals for each single property which might not yet be available.

What is the best way to completely deactivate a portion of QML code and to enable it as soon as a signal is triggered?

Comment: Put all the window content inside the `Loader` and so load it when the trigger fires.

Comment: Other than justtack wrote, you would actually use a `Loader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal experience is to not give data to your view components, don't bind them. For example, set your text value to an empty string or don't set it, set your image component source to an empty string or don't set it at first. When your signal comes in with data ready, you assign the data to the views at that time.